# Python write to file maths generator

Tags: python

hello i have my code for a random maths quiz and i want it to save the name and there score next to the file and i want it to keep the data and not write over it every time could someone please help me and add this in i would like it so it could reocrd it like this let say i played it i would like the file to be like this then if someone else took the quiz it just adds there name to the list not erase the list first

name  score

```
def quiz():
    import random
    import time

    name=input("What is your name?")
    print ("Alright",name,"Welcome to your maths quiz")
    score=0
    question=0
    for question in range (1,11):
        ops=['*','+','-']
        rand=random.randint(1,10)
        rand2=random.randint(1,10)
        operation=random.choice(ops)
        maths = eval(str(rand) + operation + str(rand2))
        print ("Question",question)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print (rand,operation,rand2)
        question=question+1
        d=int(input ("What is your answer:"))
        if d==maths:
            print ("Correct")
            score=score+1
        else:
            print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)


    if score >=7:
        print ("Well done you got",score,"out of 10")
    else:
        print ("Unlucky you got",score,"out of 10")

    percentage=score/10*100
    print ("You got",percentage,"%")



    f = open('results.txt','w')
    f.write('%d' % score)
    f.close()

playagain = 'yes'
while playagain == 'yes': 
    quiz()
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playagain = input()
```

Comment: `f = open('results.txt','a')`

Comment: okay thank you added that is there a way to make it go to a new line instead of just next to it also how can i add the name in there also

Comment: use `writeln` instead of `write`, to add the name, do the same as you did with the score.

Comment: @DannyBradshaw if my solution is what you are looking for please select it as your answer so that it can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
f = open('results.txt','w')
```

to

```
f = open('results.txt','a')
```

Read the python docs for File I/O. `'w'` overwrites an existing file

if you want the name with the score

```
f.write('{} : {}\n'.format(name, score) )
```

Comment: okay thank you this works well is there a way to do it so its put on a new line everytime

Comment: just add a `\n` to the `.write`